# How to run eclipse luna mac os with java 7

Tags: eclipse, macos, java-7, eclipse-luna

i need to execute a ant script inside eclipse luna using java 7.
The problem is that if i try to change the path with jenv or try to set JAVA_HOME inside eclipse the ant script inside eclipse is always executed with java 6.
The OS is macOS Sierra.

I have to use eclipse.ini ?

Thanks

Comment: Is your project set to compile against a Java 7 Runtime?

Comment: It's not a problem compiling the project (I know how change the project compiler setting). The problem problem was using ant external tool ant inside eclipse. greg-449 in answer below solved the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are running the Ant script the normal way you can configure this in the configuration for the script.

Open the External Tools Configuration dialog using 'Run > External Tools > External Tools Configuration...'.

Find your script in the 'Ant Build' section and then look at the 'JRE' tab where you can set the JRE/JDK to anything you have told Eclipse about.